# When iterating through array, first value is always "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a quiz and I'm trying to iterate through the elements in the HTML form (radio buttons), adding the value of the button to a string if it is checked. However, the first thing added to the string is always "undefined" and I can't work out why. Please note, I'm very new to Javascript.

I've tried changing the way the for loop works - using `(inputs.length+1)`, or setting `i` to `1` instead of `0`. This doesn't seem to be the issue however. I've also tried checking that the value isn't undefined before adding it to the string (as shown below), but it still results in the first part of the string saying "undefined".

```
var chosen_result; //the string to add values to
var temp;
var inputs = document.forms["townquiz"].elements;
for (i = 0; i < (inputs.length-1); i++) {
temp = inputs[i];
if((temp.checked) && !(temp.value == "undefined")){
chosen_result += temp.value;
```

Actual Result: undefinedABC

Expected Result: ABC

where A, B and C are values of the radio buttons in the HTML form.

Comment: Because your variable starts out as `undefined`. And you only ever concat(`chosen_result +=`) never set it to an initial empty string

Comment: `var chosen_result; //the string to add values to` - **Not a string yet.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regards to strings, the `+=` operator concatenates the current value and a new value. `chosen_result` is `undefined` because it was declared but not initialized. Simply set `chosen_result` to an empty string:

```
var chosen_result = ""; //the string to add values to
var temp;
var inputs = document.forms["townquiz"].elements;
for (i = 0; i < (inputs.length-1); i++) {
temp = inputs[i];
if((temp.checked) && !(temp.value == "undefined")){
chosen_result += temp.value;
```

Comment: @kumikan Well, not really. Dynamically typed languages have to assume what type of data you want and it does a pretty good job. If you take any type of data and concat with a string, it'll do its best to convert the original value to a string and append.

Answer (score 3):

Assign an empty string to `chosen_result` like `chosen_result = ''` to avoid the value being `undefined` when you append to it.

Answer (score 1):

String addition in JavaScript can be somewhat strange, because it uses [coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion). When you declare `chosen_result`, you're not setting it to anything, so its type is `undefined`. When you add a string to `undefined`, JavaScript will turn it into a string, then concatenate it. `String(undefined)`, however, is `"undefined"`, so, what you're really doing is

```
"undefined" += "ABC"
```

To fix this problem, initialize `chosen_result` as an empty string:

```
var chosen_result = ""
```

This way, it won't be coerced.